# Access Month Calendar View

Tags: ms-access, vba

Does anybody have any link to Access Calendar .ocx or regular forms that would be compatible with Office 2016 64 bit.

I am just coming up with a lot of old stuff that was designed for A97.

Ideally, I would like to be able to visualise a Union Query with dates etc pulled from 3/4 different sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OCX on 64 bit systems not recommended, pure VBA solutions better. For instance you can find the code for such kind date picker [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251104(v=office.14).aspx), see "Grab the code" on the right.